# Whether Rect.midleft (or midright, etc.) is a tuple

Tags: python, pygame, tuples

I've been working on a space shooting game in which the particles attached to the ship's engine resemble the fire that comes out of the engine. I used `ship_rect.midleft` to give the information on the position that the particles were generated, yet the command prompt responded to me:

> ```py
> ship_particle [0][0] += ship_particle [1]
> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
> ```

What should I do with this?

```py
ship_particles = []
    
while True 
    ......
    ship_particles.append([[ship_rect.midleft],-3, random.randint(5,6)])
    for ship_particle in ship_particles:
        ship_particle [0][0] += ship_particle [1]
        ship_particle [2] -= 0.1
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,255),ship_particle[0],ship_particle[2])
        ship_particle_copy = [ship_particle for ship_particle in ship_particles if ship_particle[2]>0]
        ship_particles = ship_particle_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

`ship_rect.midleft` is a tuple. Actually you are appending a list with 1 tuple. Since you cannot change the elements of a tuple you have to make a list from the tuple. Use the [asterisk (*) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) and unpacking the tuple. Just add `[*ship_rect.midleft]` instead of  `[ship_rect.midleft]`

<s>`ship_particles.append([[ship_rect.midleft],-3, random.randint(5,6)])`</s>

```py
ship_particles.append([[*ship_rect.midleft], -3, random.randint(5,6)])
```

Alternatively use the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function:

```py
ship_particles.append([list(ship_rect.midleft), -3, random.randint(5,6)])
```

---

Compare

```py
ship_rect = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 20, 20)
print([ship_rect.midleft])
```

> ```
> [(10, 20)]
> ```

and

```py
ship_rect = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 20, 20)
print([*ship_rect.midleft])
```

> ```
> [10, 20]
> ```